# How to stop Telerik RadWindow from always reloading on the next PostBack 2

Tags: telerik, postback, radwindow

Greetings to you dear colleagues!

Prompt.

I have here a situation - there is a component RadWindows RadButton button on it by pressing a button in the RadGrid RadWindows component is set to Visible = true; But after PostBack and shape RadWindows disappears. But going into the RadWindows everything remains as it was changed to reboot.

Question: How to prevent reload the page.

Who does not know what are the components of Rad Teleric.

The source code can throw if it helps.

Thank you, Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set DestroyOnClose="true" to prevent the window from reopening after close or postback. It sounds like you may be setting the Visible property to true using server-side code. This is bad practice which leads to issues like you describe. RadWindows should be opened via the client-side methods.

On the server side use this code to open a window from the client side using the RadWindow.Show client-side method while having DestoryOnClose set to true. You can customize the script string should you want to use the RadWindow.Open() method to pass a url to the window.

```
    private void ShowWindow()
    {
        string script = "function f(){$find(\"" + YourRadWindow.ClientID + "\").show(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider opening it with JavaScript, this will let you stop using these unnecessary postbacks: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening.html.
Use OnClientClicking of the RadButton: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/12-08-10/migrating-onclientclick-handlers-from-asp-button-to-telerik-s-asp-net-ajax-button.aspx.

You can also use AJAX to prevent full postbacks that will dispose (and thus, hide) the RadWindow: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radwindow-ajaxifying.html.

Read this sticky to see how to open it from the server if you need to. If you set VisibleOnPageLoad to true it will re-show after postbacks, so you will only need to take care of setting the property back to false when you need to: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-radwindow-from-the-server.aspx.